# $window.open called in a promise breaks the second promise

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, window.open, angular-promise, livereload

I am pretty new to angularjs. Love it but sometimes get surprises that I just can't find an answer.

I have a function that lets the user build a list to a file by clicking a link. This can take up to a minute so the user can build different lists at the same time. The meaning is that once the file is build a popup appears to download it.
All of this works when only 1 file is build. After a half a minute the download popup shows up. But when 2 are build at the same time the second POST is cancelled (it arrives in the error callback) once the pop-up of the first appears.

If I remove $window.open both POST are finished succesfully and I get both fileId's in the console log.

Clearly the problem lies with $window.open. But why? What am I doing wrong or how can I solve this? Anyone an idea? I have been searching for hours already but can't seem to find anything on this case.

```
 $scope.idPromise = $http.post(restPath, $scope.data)
              .then(function(data){
console.log(data.data);
console.log(data.data.fileId);
$window.open(restPath + 'files/' + data.data.fileId, '_self');
},function(error){
console.log('promise error')
            });
```

So when two lists are build without window.open in the code I get something like this in my console:

> POST http://localhost:8080/xxx-rest/rest/lijsten/vastelijsten/gezinshoofdenMetLeden 200 OK 1m
>
> POST http://localhost:8080/xxx-rest/rest/lijsten/vastelijsten/gezinshoofdenMetLeden 200 OK 1m 40s
>
> report3545743463669473959.xlsx
>
> report4733168386603499105.xlsx

when window.open is placed in the code:

> POST
>   http://localhost:8080/xxx-rest/rest/lijsten/vastelijsten/gezinshoofdenMetLeden
>   200 OK 1m
>
> POST
>   http://localhost:8080/xxx-rest/rest/lijsten/vastelijsten/gezinshoofdenMetLeden
>   x 56,39s
>
> report1588183186872251177.xlsx
>
> promise error

As you can see the last POST is stopped as soon as the first POST gets a response, so for the second POST no response is gotten.

**Update**

It seems the problem lies with the grunt server and the liveReload Protocol. My college had always told me to ignore this error but it is now clear that because the page loses connection that the promise fails.

Does anyone have experience with grunt and liveReload? Can I fix this? Will it work on a production server?

The console error I get:

> De verbinding met ws://localhost:35729/livereload werd onderbroken
>   tijdens het laden van de pagina. this.socket = new
>   this.WebSocket(this._uri);

(translated: the connection with... was interrupted)

Comment: What are you trying to do with $window.open ?

Comment: an excel or word file is opened

Comment: Could you please post some more code? Does `$scope` belong to a controller or a directive?

Comment: actually it belongs to the instance controller of a modal. The strange thing is that it works correctly with multiple POST as long as I do not use window.open

For the first document a correct pop-up appears. when the user clicks this popup excel or word succesfully opens.
The pop-up appears when the POST gives the filename as a response. But if different POST are send they all go to onerror as soon as the first pop-up appears. Without window.open all POST give the correct response when logged

But why would this be a scope problem as I get the correct fileId's when I do not use window.open

Comment: I don't think more code will help to understand the problem. As I said the problem lies with window.open All promises/POST that are busy when the first window.open is launched are send to the error callback. Unless window.open can changes something to the scope? I could add more code but it is hard to keep it generic. Actually the call to the rest is done in the modal instance controller when the user clicks submit and the modal is closed. The modal is inside a directive that sends a call to the rest server to build an excel file and respond with the filename.

Comment: I changed it so that the links appear on the top of the page when they are downloaded. This works but if you click on a link while another list is build the promise goes again to the error. It seems the problem lies with the grunt server and the liveReload protocol. Does anyone have experience with this? Would it than work on a real server?